# Datetime FromDate To Date

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a Window from that contains 2 date Pickers dtpFromDate and dtpToDate, I want to know how to validate that user selects From date the first date of selected month and To date is the last date of the same month.

Comment: Sounds like you really only need a month picker - you can create first/last days of the month yourself from that data.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, having a months dropdown should be enough for your needs (though you may also require a years dropdown).

You can construct the first and last dates from that piece of information easily enough.

```
var fromDate = new DateTime(theYear, theMonth, 1);
var toDate = fromDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```